# Socket.io function only working once, then stops

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

So... I decided for some reason to completely go for a socket.io server sided handling, instead of having route post. However I have ran into the issue where a function will only work once. The second time, everything works great, except the database doesn't update. (There might be other things wrong going on in the background but I can't seem to find it)... oh! And the client side value emitting only always emits 1, and will not get 2, 3, 4 etc etc.

Client side emit:

```
  $('#battle-wrapper').on('click', 'button#battlebutton', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('fight mob', $('#mobs').val());
    console.log($('#mobs').val());
  });
```

Socket.io code:

```
socket.on('fight mob', function () {
var session = socket.handshake.session;

// Player Variables
var userMhp = session.userdata.tough;
var userHp = 10;
var userDmg = session.userdata.str;
var userDef = session.userdata.tough;

//  Mob Variables
var mobid = 1;
var mobMhp = Math.floor(mobid * 50);
var mobHp = 100;
var mobDmg = 5;
var mobDef = 5;

// Statistic variables
var dmgdeltmob = 0;
var dmgdeltuser = 0;
var rounds = 0;

// Strings
// var userVictory = '';
// var mobVictory = '';
// var userDefeat = '';
// var mobDefeat = '';

// Turn Variables
var userTurn = true;

//start battle loop
while (userHp > 0 && mobHp > 0) {

  // Start BATTLE
  if (userTurn === true) {
    dmgdeltmob = userDmg;

    // mobHp = mobHp - dmgdeltmob;
    rounds += 1;
    userTurn = false;
  } else if (userTurn === false) {
    dmgdeltuser =  mobDmg;
    userHp = userHp - 10;
    rounds += 1;
    userTurn = true;
  }
}

// Start end of battle Calculations
if (userHp <= 0) { // Defeat
  console.log('Lost');
  let sql = 'UPDATE users SET ? WHERE id = ?';
  let post = {
    silver: session.userdata.silver + 1,
  };
  db.query(sql, [post, session.userdata.id], function (err) {
    console.log('1 Silver Success');
    var data = post.silver;
    socket.emit('mob test', data);
    return;
  });

} else {
  console.log('Won');
}

});
```

Comment: But what about logging on the client side, is it logging every time?

Comment: All the `consoles.logs(...)` are working as intended. The database does not update (which means the `.emit(..)` also doesn't show the updated amount after the first time. Also if I refresh and do it again it still doesn't work and it somethings throws errors of undefined variables inside of my game.ejs file (which lists mobs). I'm not sure what is causing this, maybe I do have to use a ajax post, but I'm not sure how I'd use it while using a socket emit as well.

Comment: Okay, so I have figured out what is causing it. It is the session. It is not updating the the session value. I have added a line `session.userdata.silver = post.silver;` after the `let post = ...`. And it updates. However if I refresh and run the function again, it resets the database to the way it was before I rand them the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer, maybe not the best solution, actually it probably isn't. But here is what I did, I made a session handler function that calls on login, and on refresh:

```
 function sessionHandler() {
    // Adding the logged in user to session
    var userId = session.passport.user;
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?';
    var query = db.query(sql, userId, function (err, rows) {
      session.userdata = rows[0];
      session.save();
      var dataObj = session.userdata;
      socket.emit('start up', dataObj);
      usersConnected++;
      io.emit('users online', usersConnected);
      console.log(usersConnected);
    });
  }
```

Here is a basic logic to handle the login/refresh. It seems I will need to add all of the logic into the function itself, sadly. Because everything returns undefined outside of the function, but inside the same block.

```
// User logs in
  if (session.passport === undefined) {
    socket.emit('not logged', destination);
  } else {
    if (session.userdata === undefined) {
      sessionHandler();

      // console.log(session.userdata.username + ' logged in');
    } else {
      if (session.userdata) {
        delete session.userdata;
        session.save();
        sessionHandler();
      }

      // console.log(session.userdata.username + ' refreshed their session');
    }
  }
```